# In Transactional Analysis, how can one kill or at least voice down the "Critical Parent" ego state?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, reference-request, personality, metacognition

The Parent ego state is like a tape recorder full of pre- judged, prejudiced, pre-programmed statements. These "taped" statements can get activated while we are in our Adult or Child and then we can actually hear them as "voices in our heads." The Parental tapes can feel good or bad depending on which Parent makes them. In other personality theories, the harmful Critical Parent voices are known as the harsh super-ego, negative self-talk, cognitive traps, low self-esteem, punitive protector or catastrophic expectations.

**My question:** What are the methods or options to either voice down or mute the Critical Parent?

---

Reference:

- [Transactional Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_analysis)
- [The ego-state (or Parent–Adult–Child
  (PAC)) models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_analysis#The_ego-state_(or_Parent%E2%80%93Adult%E2%80%93Child_(PAC))_models)

Comment: Please be aware that this covers areas of psychology [considered by some to be pseudoscientific](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2242)